# Stuck in a loop of errors: unreachable statement and no return statement provided

Tags: java, unreachable-code, unreachable-statement

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public static int dc (String s,int k, int c){
  String s1, s2;
  int m, n;
  if (check(s, k) != -1) {
    int p = check(s, k);
    c++;
    s1 = s.substring(0, p) + s.substring(p + 1);
    s2 = s.substring(0, p + 1) + s.substring(p + 2);
    if ((check(s1, k) == -1) || (check(s2, k) == -1)) {
      return c;
    } else {
      m = dc(s1, k, c);
      n = dc(s2, k, c);
      if (m > n) {
        return n;
      } else {
        return m;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the error says that there is a missing return statement (not sure which scenario have I missed). But when I add a return statement at the end, it shows that return statement unreachable. I've found an helpful answer here: [Unreachable return statement still throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336303/unreachable-return-statement-still-throws-error) and I have tried putting it in a try catch block but it still asks for a return statement. Even though the compiler knows that anything I write in the end is redundant, why is it still showing an error?

Comment: This method isn't missing a `return` statement on any branch. Perhaps the problem is with your `check` method? Could you include its code?

Comment: You must have a return statement at the end, in case the first if condition is false. Your life would be easier if you use proper indentation.

Comment: The code goes into this method only if check isn't -1. Should I post the entire code?

Comment: You've said the method returns an int, but what happens if that first if fails? You can only get away with no return statement in this kind of situation if the signature for the method returns void.

Comment: I just added that if statement to explain it to my friend. Removing it makes it work. This was stupid of me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first check `check(s, k)` returns `-1` then you don't return anything

Answer (score 1):

The first if Block doesn't have else...

if(check(s,k)!=-1){

...... 
}

Answer (score 0):

`public static int dc(String s, int k,int c){
        String s1,s2; int m,n;
        if(check(s,k)!=-1)
        {
            int p=check(s,k);
            c++;
            s1=s.substring(0,p)+s.substring(p+1);
            s2=s.substring(0,p+1)+s.substring(p+2);
            if((check(s1,k)==-1)||(check(s2,k)==-1)){
                return c;
            }
            else{
                m=dc(s1,k,c); 
                n=dc(s2,k,c); 
                if(m>n){
                    return n;
                } 
                else{
                    return m;
                }
            }
        }
    // MISSING RETURN BELOW
        return n;
    }`

I suggest using an IDE like eclipse, it'll help you spot these things. It literally added the statement for me.

Comment: Well I do use Eclipse but I was directly coding it on codechef so I got lazy and didn't add indentations